# Error will be Raised when parse data into elasticsearch from mysql

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta -d 
           "{
                "type" : "jdbc",
                      "jdbc" : 
                       {
                        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springtest",
                        "user" : "root",
                        "password" : "root",
                        "sql" : "select * from register",
                        "index" : "my_register", 
                        "type" : "my_register_type" 
                       }
           }"
```

**the connection successfull but error tab will generated like**

```
error: NoClassSettingsException[Failed to load class with value [jdbc]]; nested:   
ClassNotFoundException[jdbc];
```

Comment: please see if my new try for connection this is also gave me same error bro

Comment: did you perform all the steps mentioned there? https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: How many nodes do you have? Did you do step 5 on all nodes?

Comment: yess i done all step from download Download MySQL JDBC driver to -XPUT

Answer (score 0):

I presume you need to add

`"driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"`

to your jdbc definition.

Also, check that you have done all the steps mentioned there: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart

(especially pp.4 and 5, related to registering MySQL driver with your ElasticSearch instance)